# Ansible Passing variable to line in file with stdout_lines

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

```
name: the file
    raw: cat "{{item}}"
    with_items: "{{groups['firewall']}}"
    when: inventory_hostname == item
    register: output3

debug: var=output3.results

name: Copy File to Local Machine
    local_action: lineinfile dest=/Users/{{inventory_hostname}} line="{{item}}"
    with_dict: "{{ output3 }}"
```

How do I get output3.stdout_lines to be the line item? The current method I have copies the entire thing which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
- name: Copy File to Local Machine
  local_action: lineinfile dest=/Users/{{inventory_hostname}} line="{{item.1}}"
  with_subelements:
      - "{{output3.results}}"
      - stdout_lines
      - flags:
          skip_missing: yes
```

I suppose this is some hardware-box without Python support?
Otherwise there are more elegant ways to fetch files.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot.